# How can i set image circular

Tags: ios

I have done following code but it does not work. It shows me in circle but in crop image format.

I want to fit image to circle.

```
UIImage * defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"empty.png"];
self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:defaultImage];

CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(90.0f, 100.0f, self.myImageView.frame.size.width/1.5,self.myImageView.frame.size.height/1.5);
[self.myImageView setFrame:myFrame];

[self.myImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

self.myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.myImageView.frame.size.width/2;       
self.myImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.myImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;

self.myImageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:self.myImageView];
```

Comment: change this line  `self.myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = Yes;`

Comment: And `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, because with `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` you might not get the whole round shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method

```
-(void)setRoundedView:(UIImageView *)roundedView toDiameter:    
(float)newSize;
{
    CGPoint saveCenter = roundedView.center;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, 
    roundedView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
    roundedView.frame = newFrame;
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
    roundedView.center = saveCenter;
}
```

Now call the method with your imageview

```
[self setRoundedView:self.myImageView toDiameter:self.myImageView.frame.size.width];
 self.myImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

In short,

```
anyView.layer.cornerRadius = anyView.frame.size.width/2;

Make sure that clipsToBound property of that view is enabled.
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score -1):

**Set width & height equal to Your imageView, then set cornerRadius of imageView to half of width & height.**

```
[self createRoundUIView:self.userProfileImageView sizeDiameter:self.userProfileImageView.frame.size.width];
```

And add following code to bellow method,

```
-(void)createRoundUIView:(UIImageView *)inputView sizeDiameter:(float)diameterSize
{
  CGPoint saveCenter = inputView.center;
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(inputView.frame.origin.x, inputView.frame.origin.y, diameterSize, diameterSize);
  inputView.frame = frame;
  inputView.layer.cornerRadius = diameterSize / 2.0;
  inputView.center = saveCenter;
  inputView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}
```